# Freeman Chain Code Infinite Loop [4-adjacency]

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to implement Freeman Chain Code [4 adjacency] on matlab using the notation shown in the picture:
[image: 4 adjacency]

My code gives correct chain code for multiple small matrices I tested it with. However I run into an infinite while loop for some connected components when I run the code on my actual image file. By infinite loop I mean, it doesnt loop between just two points, but it keeps on traversing the component without reaching the starting point.

I will explain the approach here.

My connected component is of 4 adjacency, and all pixels are marked as "label" in the matrix.
I start from the first top left most pixel (x,y) of the component and traverse using the following rules:
My initial traversal (xT,yT) is left to right. horDir = 0, since 0 is for right.

```
while(true)
if (horDir == 0)
    go UP, or RIGHT, or DOWN, or LEFT (adjust x,y)
    if (went LEFT)
        horDir = 2
else
    go DOWN, or LEFT, or UP, or RIGHT (adjust x,y)
    if (went LEFT)
        horDir = 0
if (xT,yT == x,y)
    break;
```

When i decide to move in any position, I make sure that my last movement was not the opposite of it, to avoid infinite loop. For example, if I reached (x,y) via a 0 movement, my code makes sure that I do a 2 movement after checking 1 and 3 movements, so this is not what causing me to enter an infinite loop I think.

If there is ambiguity in what I am trying to achieve, I am trying to do this:
[image]

Any insight would be appreciated.
I can post my complete code if required, however it would be quite tedious to read.

Comment: It is not clear - what problem are you solving with Freeman codes? To avoid visiting cells again, just mark them as 'visited'

Comment: @MBo I edited the question with the a picture that explains what I am trying to do.
Some cells would have to be visited again in order to reach back to the starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the algorithm as shown [in this answer to a somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50842196/7328782), which is further described on [my blog here](http://www.crisluengo.net/archives/324).

It does 8-connected chain codes, but it’s easy to adapt that code to 4-connected chains.