# How does MATLAB's `regionprops` function computes perimeter?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have found that the function uses [chain codes](http://www.crisluengo.net/archives/310) to encode the boundary of the shape, and then computes the perimeter [this way](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/357994-perimeter-used-by-regionprops) using this formula:

```
perimeter = sum(isEven)*0.980 + sum(~isEven)*1.406 - sum(isCorner)*0.091;
```

What I do not know, however, is how this chain code is computed in some special cases.

Consider the following example (for which MATLAB yields a perimeter of 10.0150):

```
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     0     0     1
```

How does MATLAB defines/computes the perimeter around the one pixel wide line attached to the 2x2 square on the left?

More precisely:

If I denote non-zero border pixels using letters (all 1s are borders in this example):

```
 a     d     e     f     g
 b     c                 h
```

A chain code could start at, say, `a`. If we compute it clockwise, it would then continue at `c`, `e`, `f`... Which means it cannot come back to `a`, otherwise it would have to go twice over the same letter (even more than twice if there are 1px wide lines attached to other 1px wide lines etc).

Comment: The very next post on that blog describes an algorithm to obtain the chain codes: https://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/324

Comment: My problem is how to handle the 1px-wide lines between or around shapes (cf the two examples above). Matlab doesn't ignore them, but it would be complicated to represent them using a chain code.

Comment: @Urefeu do you have any specific question other than "anyone know how"? Cris has shown you how.

Comment: I have edited my initial question. I hope it is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps in obtaining chain codes: tracing the boundary and encoding the coordinates as chain codes. This latter step is trivial, I won't go into details. Tracing the boundary is what I think this question is about.

Typically what is traced are the object pixels that form the boundary (i.e. have at least one background neighbor). It is important that this happen in order, just listing these pixels is not enough. But do note that this description of the boundary is biased: the true object is larger than the polygon formed by joining the centers of the pixels at the object boundary. A perimeter computation needs to take this into account (as discussed in the blog post you linked).

This code is adapted slightly from [this blog post](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/324). `img` is a logical array:

```
% Data for chain code encoding:
directions = [ 1, 0
               1,-1
               0,-1
              -1,-1
              -1, 0
              -1, 1
               0, 1
               1, 1];
% Get a start point, any pixel on the boundary is OK:
indx = find(img,1)-1;           % 0-based indexing is easier
% Image sizes
sz = [size(img,2),size(img,1)]; % x,y sizes, rather than y,x sizes
% Coordinates for start point
start = [floor(indx/sz(2)),0];
start(2) = indx-(start(1)*sz(2));
% Initialize algorithm
cc = [];                        % The chain code
coord = start;                  % Coordinates of the current pixel
dir = 1;                        % The starting direction
% Loop till full boundary is traced
while 1
   newcoord = coord + directions(dir+1,:);
   if all(newcoord>=0) && all(newcoord<sz) ...
         && img(newcoord(2)+1,newcoord(1)+1)
      cc = [cc,dir];
      coord = newcoord;
      dir = mod(dir+2,8);
   else
      dir = mod(dir-1,8);
   end
   if all(coord==start) && dir==1 % back to starting situation
      break;
   end
end
```

As you can see here, the algorithm starts at a random pixel, and picks a direction to go around. Then it follows the boundary by finding the next neighbor in the given direction. The linked blog post has details explaining how this neighbor is found. In short, you look in the current direction, for the first neighboring object pixel that has a background neighbor. Given the current location and direction we came from, it is provable that the neighbor in a specific direction will be a background pixel. Going in clockwise (or anticlockwise, pick one) direction around the current point, starting with that background pixel, the first object pixel will guaranteed be a boundary pixel. We add that to out list and continue.

The algorithm terminates when we reach the start position **and direction**. The 1-pixel thick section of an object will thus be visited twice, to complete the boundary trace.

Comment: Thank you, this works very fine. I implemented it and I have a difference of less than 10e-2 with Matlab's perimeter so it's perfect.